# How to efficiently manipulate strings in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

How do I efficiently make changes to a string in Javascript without creating a new string every time I make a change? The attached code
illustrates this as each "result +=" operation
will generate a new string.

The idea of using a Unit8Array as a work area appears to fail because converting to a string is just as inefficient.

```
; Use mask to change characters in string to a
; '-' if mask dictates that. 
function maskOutput(input, mask) {
 let result = '';
 for (let i=0; i < input.length; i++){
    if (mask.charAt(i) === 'X') {
      result += '-';
    } else {
       result += input.charAt(i);
    }
 }
 return result;
}
```

Comment: You can't, strings are immutable.

Comment: Actually, repeated `+=` is well-optimised in engines. Is this really a problem in your application, did you benchmark your current solution?

Comment: Maybe you should create the result using `String.replace` and a RegExp object, the RegExp would do the dirty work for you, and you would have created a single string only.

Comment: "*converting to a string is just as inefficient.*" - what makes you say that? How did you write it? Btw I'd recommend a `Uint16Array` if you want to go for that, it matches the JS string representation more closely.

Comment: @Bergi It's good news that the engines are well optimized for this case.  
I was hoping to find an array implementation that provided a useful toString() method but the ones tried produced unusable output like "-,-,-,0,0,0,0".

Comment: @user17926117 Just use `.join('')` instead of `.join(',')` or `.toString()`

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I'd do is check whether the temporary strings were actually causing a problem for my page/app, because JavaScript engines are **extremely** good at optimizing common issues like lots of temporary strings, **especially** in cases like your `maskOutput` where the string is the result of string concatenation. (V8, the engine in Chrome and elsewhere, does it when necessary by combining partial strings into a linked list.) It seems unlikely that the string concatenation in your `maskOutput` function is a bottleneck for your page/app. It used to be fairly standard practice that you'd see code building up a large string by using an array and then `.join("")` at the end, because it was faster circa 2009, but JavaScript engines have moved on a **lot** since then and I remember it became faster to just use `+=` on a string several years ago.

If there were some use case (memory pressure, whatever) where the temporary strings were a problem, you could use a plain array¹ of individual characters, converting once (from string to array) at the outset if needed (not in your case) and at the end (from array to string). But for a short string like the ones I imagine `maskOutput` handles, as you say, the overhead wouldn't be worth it.

But just for completeness:

```
function maskOutput(input, mask) {
    const len = input.length;
    let result = Array(len); // Some engines actually do optimize this
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (mask[i] === 'X') { // No need for a method call
            result[i] = "-";
        } else {
            result[i] = input[i];
        }
    }
    return result.join("");
}
```

---

¹ `Uint8Array` would be a poor choice, because:

- Strings are made up of 16-bit values (UTF-16 *code units*). If you want to use a typed array, `Uint16Array` would be more appropriate.
- Putting a value into a `Uint8Array`/`Uint16Array` requires converting it from JavaScript's number type to an 8-bit/16-bit unsigned integer (and the converse on reading), which is **really** cheap but isn't free. And presumably you'd have to use `charCodeAt` to get the value to store.

Comment: I just saw a SO post (maybe a week ago) where it was stated, that modern browsers have optimized string concatenations so that they're faster than building an array and then joining it to a string. I couldn't find the post, but there were some benchmarkings as evidence.

Comment: @Teemu - Yeah. I think that point was cleared several years ago in fact, I remember it happening ("it" being the point where most engines were faster with `+=` than adding to an array and joining it). So it would need to be in response to an issue of memory pressure or some such, and I just can't see it. :-)

Comment: Do browsers actually optimize `Array(len)` now? Not that I'll ever write code where this is super relevant.

Comment: Probably the question is a result of kinda "duck typing", it looks slow, so it has to be slow = ). I'd reacall the aforementioned post was few years old, I'll try to find it ...

Comment: @Domino - Yeah, I was surprised by that too, but Mathias Bynens of the V8 team set me straight on it, and confirmed just recently that [this article](https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds) is still up-to-date. Which is why I use `Array.from({length: 10_000_000}, () => { /*...something filling it in*/ })` instead of `Array.from(Array(10_000_000), () => { /*...something filling it in*/ })` in the extremely rare case where I'm working with blocks that big (well, I do it by habit even with smaller ones now, but you understand).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  But that article/video is the exact reason why I asked. It warns that using `Array(len)` creates a holey array whereas `Array()` followed by a bunch of `push` of the same type is more efficient. The `Array.from` trick I've used though, that makes sense.

Comment: @Domino - Yes, but we're not going to use the array so it's not important. The key bit in regard my example is that it creates backing storage for the array: https://twitter.com/mathias/status/1392132666544246784. So if I'm not going to use it (as in my example), I want to avoid that, so I use `{length: x}` instead. :-)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the answers and information. I feel thoroughly answered and also have some homework to do with the references you guys provided. Thanks!!